# Significance of OMX_IndexParamVideoAvc for an OMX Video Decoder

Tags: android, video, h.264, openmax

I have a query on the significance of `OMX_IndexParamVideoAvc` for an `OMX` video decoder. Specifically, my query is: Should an `OMX Video Decoder` support the index `OMX_IndexParamVideoAvc` as part of `get` and `set` functionalities?

**Background:**

From my understanding, this index is more useful from a `video encoder` perspective, as this is employed by an `OMXIL Client` to query the underlying component on the existing support and further configure the encoder as the client's needs.

From a specification perspective, I observe that the specification does indicate the support for index `OMX_IndexParamVideoAvc` on `VPB+0` for a video decoder as in page 359 of the [specification](http://www.khronos.org/files/openmax_il_spec_1_1_2.pdf). In this section, only `profile` and `level` are populated.

Potentially I feel that this index could be employed for `OMX_GetParameter` to retrieve the max. profile and level supported by the component. However, the same could also be retrieved from `OMX_IndexParamVideoProfileLevelQuerySupported`.

Hence,my main doubts are:

1. Should an `OMX video decoder` support the index `OMX_IndexParamVideoAvc`?
2. If this index is supported, then what should be the default values when an `OMXIL` client queries the same, say in `LOADED` state?
3. The point where this index could logically be filled only after the component is in `EXECUTING` state and the first buffer with `OMX_BUFFERFLAG_CODECONFIG` has been decoded. Until this state is reached, should the decoder populate only max. `profile` and `level` fields and set other fields to zero?
4. Is there a practical scenario where this index is queried from an `OMX video decoder`? A [quick search](http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/search?q=OMX_IndexParamVideoAvc&defs=&refs=&path=&hist=&project=abi&project=art&project=bionic&project=bootable&project=build&project=cts&project=dalvik&project=developers&project=development&project=device&project=docs&project=external&project=frameworks&project=hardware&project=libcore&project=libnativehelper&project=ndk&project=packages&project=pdk&project=prebuilts&project=sdk&project=system&project=tools) on `android` shows a predominant support for this index from `encoders`. Even in `AOSP` sources, the support for this index from `Exynos` implementations is for `profile` and `level`. Hence, I am not particularly convinced of the intended use of this index for `OMX video decoders`.

**Common Implementations:**

When I tried to search for common implementations, I found some interesting data. TI and Broadcomm encoders support this index (in some cases partially) as shown in [`OMX_VENC`](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/OMX_VENC) and [`omx.broadcomm.video_encode`](http://home.nouwen.name/RaspberryPi/documentation/ilcomponents/video_encode.html). However, a similar search for decoders as in [`OMX_VDEC`](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/OMX_VDEC) and [`omx.broadcommn.video_decode`](http://www.jvcref.com/files/PI/documentation/ilcomponents/video_decode.html) showed that there is no apparent support for this index in decoders. The only exception to this understanding is found in samsung's aries implementation as shown in [decoder code here](https://gitorious.org/replicant/device_samsung_aries-common/source/9ff4c660a554dc2816db67004fccb10f6ad0e0fa%3aaries/sec_mm/sec_omx/sec_omx_component/video/dec/h264dec/SEC_OMX_H264dec.c).

Any pointers/comments/suggestions would be highly helpful.Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are right it should be used for enc component setup.

`OMX_IndexParamVideoProfileLevelQuerySupported` used [like here](https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/platform/hardware/qcom/media/tree/mm-video-v4l2/vidc/vdec/src/omx_vdec_msm8974.cpp) along with `OMX_IndexParamVideoProfileLevelCurrent` covers the case and purpose of `OMX_IndexParamVideoAvc` is to get/set the rest of `OMX_VIDEO_PARAM_AVCTYPE`

I think that providing max supported values via `OMX_IndexParamVideoAvc` might be missleading.